A tricky requirement for helmfile
When I only use helm, the server chart looks like this (assuming that when I put # in front of the 10021 line, the helm upgrade is removing the deployment associated with 10021)
root@master01:~/helmfile# ll
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   93 Apr  9 12:04 ./
drwx------ 39 root root 4096 Apr  9 12:14 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1172 Apr  9 10:59 helmfile.yaml
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  111 Apr  9 11:00 kubedeploy/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    6 Apr  9 12:04 prod.yaml
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   60 Apr  9 12:14 server/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   32 Apr  9 10:36 test.yaml
root@master01:~/helmfile# cat server/values.yaml 
image:
  repo: test.roh5server.com/roh5server


server:
  10001: {image: "k8s-roh5server",tag: "v14" ,start: "main_logic",   thread: 1, MAX_RPC_AGENT: 1}
  10021: {image: "roh5server",tag: "202403071451-74" ,start: "main_logic",   thread: 8, MAX_RPC_AGENT: 8}

replicas: 1


service:
  type: ClusterIP

ingressClassName: nginx

ingressTls: game-ingress-secret

host:
  roh5server: server-ol-ind.xxxxxxxxx.com 
  ro3micro: center-ol-ind.xxxxxxxxx.com

Then when I want to restart the 10021 deployment with my undo #, can I use helmfile to improve my ideas
Now the structure is like this, I would like to write a few lines of code (e.g. 10021) in the prod.yaml file, just to achieve the same as #102201 ..... The same effect
root@master01:~/helmfile# tree   ./  -L 2
./
├── helmfile.yaml
├── kubedeploy
│   ├── Chart.yaml
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── templates
│   └── values.yaml
├── prod.yaml
├── server
│   ├── Chart.yaml
│   ├── templates
│   └── values.yaml
└── test.yaml



How is Helmfile involved currently?  (For example, do you have some sort of values.yaml.gotmpl file already?)  Are you trying to restart the one Deployment, conditionally enable or disable it, or something else?

Thanks for the reply, I've dealt with the problem for now (via complex judgement statements)@DavidMaze
